# iTextPDF - Second PDF file generated displays text from First generated PDF file

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am using iTextPDF to generate PDFs getting data from some text inputs.

When I run the application and create first PDF, it is generated as expected.

Then I change some values and generate another, this is where problem arises.  The last entry displayed on first PDF is printed on top of the first entry of the second generated PDF.

Not sure why this is happening? Is it being saved to a buffer or something, not really sure.

Here is the code for generating PDF:

```
  public class ExportTicket implements Action{

     PdfPCell titleCell = new PdfPCell();
     PdfPCell contentCell = new PdfPCell();

     public String performAction(HttpServletRequest request) throws PewException {

        // CREATING DOCUMENT (ITEXTPDF)
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Ticket_" + ticketNo + ".pdf"));

        // Fonts
        Font headingFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

        // Open Document to Write
        document.open();

        // Table Creation
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setTotalWidth(200);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{ 5, 10 });
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        // Add Ticket Number
        contentCell.addElement(new Chunk("Ticket Number: " + ticketNo, headingFont));
        contentCell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(contentCell);

        // Add table to Document & Close Document
        document.add(table)
        document.close();
      }
  }
```

Please see attached images for output, First one displays first file generation and second one displays 2nd File generation,

[image: PDF File Generated First]
            **First Generated PDF File for Ticket Number: 20170034**
[image: PDF File Generated Second]
            **Second Generated PDF File for Ticket Number: 20170035**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have strange priorities. You think you should save processing time by creating a `PdfPCell` only once (in spite of the fact that you always need a new instance), but you waste processing time by creating the font over and over again (while you could easily reuse it).

This is an improved version of your class (I assumed that you get the `ticketNo` from the request):

```
public class ExportTicket implements Action{

    // Fonts
    Font headingFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

    public String performAction(HttpServletRequest request) throws PewException {
        String ticketNo = request.getParameter("ticketNo");
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Ticket_" + ticketNo + ".pdf"));
        // Open Document to Write
        document.open();

        // Table Creation
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setTotalWidth(200);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{ 5, 10 });
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        // Add Ticket Number
        PdfPCell contentCell = new PdfPCell()
        contentCell.addElement(new Chunk("Ticket Number: " + ticketNo, headingFont));
        contentCell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(contentCell);

        // Add table to Document & Close Document
        document.add(table)
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you never reset 'contentCell'?

Or is it a value wich is resetted?

Comment: Yes, I think that the `ExportTicket` class is reused, and since the `contentCell` is created only once, the content added to that cell accumulates. See my answer for the adapted code.